# Asp.net - Upload a File from Client to Server without using Browse Button

Tags: asp.net-3.5

is there any way to upload file on server from client without using asp file upload control
with the use of java script or vb script

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file through an AJAX request. If you're using jQuery, you can check the File Upload plugin or Uploadify.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your idea....But i am not much expert in JQuery..Can u Please give me some sample code or any other links to refer...